# preconditioned conjugate gradients method on matlab and python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, optimization

I have the following matrices

```py
beta = 1e3;
mu   = 2.5e-6;
B = rand(1638400,1);
X_0=rand(51200, 32);
```

I want to solve the equation `A(X)=B` using preconditioned conjugate gradients method with the initialization value X_0, where `A(X) =mu*beta/2*x`(I have some complex operation, this is just as a reference example)
On Matlab, I found that it can be done by:

```
res=pcg(@(x)(mu*beta/2*x),B(:),1e-3,100,[],[],X_0(:));
```

(For this simple example, the solution converges at just one iteration, for my problem, it takes a bunch of iterations).

I am confused with the arguments of pcg the documentation mentions that it could be a sparse matrix, here the anonymous function could work.

I am trying to solve the same type of operation using Python.

```py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import cg

B=np.random.rand(1638400,1)
X_0=np.random.rand(51200, 32);

res=cg(lambda x:  (mu*beta/2*x), B.ravel(), tol=1e-3, maxiter=100, x0=Uk_r.ravel())
```

This approach doesn't work with python. Is there any python method to perform the operation done by Matlab? Thanks